# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'triggerInstallation_OnDemand' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have defined one parameterized method in jenkinsfile and calling it inside scripted pipeline stage but getting error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'triggerInstallation_OnDemand' found among steps"

below is my code

```
node{

  stage('trigger installation'){      
    releases.service.each { patch ->
      triggerInstallation_OnDemand(param1, param2, param3, param4)        
    }
  }
}

def triggerInstallation_OnDemand(param1, param2, param3, param4){
---------
---------
---------
logic
}
```

Note: triggerInstallation_OnDemand not returning any value